# SQL Convert string to Date works, but calculations from it does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am having trouble with a query which converts an NVarchar field into a date field.

I have used the code `convert(date,answer)` and this works, but when I try to use a case statement with this and another conversion `(convert(date,answer2))`, it doesn't work.

I have tried the following code

```
select

  CASE WHEN CP >= REF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CPY

from(

SELECT
convert(date,A.answer) as CP,

convert(date,B.answer) AS REF

from table_a as A
      left join table_b as B on A.ID = B.ID

  )m

WHERE (CASE WHEN CP >= REF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

I have tried creating another outer query, just to say where `CPY = 0`, but I get the same error.

The error I get is

> 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.'

I am not sure why the convert works perfectly, but the case when statement on the answers won't work.

**I cannot amend the data in the database, we have to use what we've got.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why `WHERE (CASE WHEN CP >= REF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0`? Why not put `CP < Ref` in your `ON`?

Comment: The root of your problem is that you are using the wrong datatype. If you want to store dates you should use the date datatype. Then you don't have to worry about conversions, your code will run faster and the issue you are facing won't happen.

Comment: @Larnu because there are multiple incidences. I need to know if there is an incidence of CP after REF, not if REF is before CP.

Comment: Locate the rows that contain bad dates and fix them. Then change the datatype.

Comment: @SeanLange As I have stated in my question, I cannot amend the data, we have to use what we've got. I work for a large government organisation, the data is stored how it's stored and it is my job to query it.

Comment: Maybe coalesce the date to something small or big, based on what you need to happen when the dates are null or invalid

Comment: @mZm I am not sure what you mean? There are not invalid dates or null dates, they are all int he same NVARCHAR format.

Comment: @BeckyPurland government or not, it doesn't change the fact that those strings aren't dates and you have no guarantee what format each string value has, assuming it *is* a date string at all. You didn't even post what is the assumed format in those strings (assumed because nothing prevents bad apps from storing strings in different formats)

Comment: *"I need to know if there is an incidence of CP after REF"*  But what you have, which is effectively `NOT(CP >= Ref)`, is a synonym for `CP < Ref`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have stated that the dates are stored in NVARCHAR fields. It is not my data, I have no control over how it is stored, having a go at people for storing data incorrectly doesn't really help me query it, and definitely doesn't help to answer my question.

Comment: @BeckyPurland `nvarchar` is a text type, not a format. Formats are eg `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`. I assume the format used is not `YYYY-MM-DD`, otherwise comparisons and ordering would work.

Comment: @becky do a `SELECT answer FROM t WHERE answer IS NOT NULL AND TRY_CONVERT(date, answer) IS NULL`. Do you get any weird value?

Comment: @BeckyPurland the question is answered by Gordon and others, even if the answer isn't what you expected. You need to know what the string format is. If you *don't* you can pray it's the same as the server's collation and try `try_convert(date, A.answer)`. Values that can't be parsed will return NULL. You can use that to find out which fields contain unexpected data. If you *do* know the format, you can add the `style` value to TRY_CONVERT and use that format. Again, failures will return NULL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The formatting is irregular. The dates are stored as 01-Apr-2019 or 23-Jan-2018 17:00, both can be in each field.

Comment: @BeckyPurland unfortunately, there's no way to say whether `04/07` is April 7th or July 4th without knowing the format in advance. If the field contains mixed `MM/DD` and `DD/MM` strings, you'll only catch those that results in obviously invalid dates.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am in the UK so we don't use 04/07 as April 7th. The only formats in will be UK formatting. The formats are as above dd-mmm-yyyy or dd-mmm-yyyy 00:00

Comment: @BeckyPurland those are the same format with an optional time component. `select try_convert(date,'01-Apr-2019 07:01')` will work`. Gordon's answer will work. If you get an error, it's due to another part of the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos try_convert(date,'01-Apr-2019 07:01') I am confused? Where does the date field go in here? I have tried try_convert(date,answer) and it does not work

Comment: @BeckyPurland `The only formats in will be UK formatting.` and yet, someone stored strings instead of dates, and even mixed up dates with date+time. Nothing is going to prevent someone from deploying an application on a server with US settings resulting in US-style dates.

Comment: @BeckyPurland *read Gordon's answer*. I posted an example you can just test yourself to see the conversion works. Use the field instead of the string value.

Comment: At the time of my comment you hadn't said you can't change the datatype. I feel your pain and it doesn't change the fact that the data is stored poorly. I hope you can figure out a solution but I suspect this is never going to be 100% as it sounds like your data is inconsistently formatted.

Comment: @BeckyPurland besides, `select convert(date,'01-Apr-2019')` also works. If the table contained the values you say you wouldn't get any errors. Use `TRY_CONVERT` to find the values that can't be parsed. PS: `dd-mmm-yyyy` is *NOT* a standard UK . Someone had to write custom formatting code to write those values. There could be a bug and values were stored eg as `01/04/2019` or `01 April 2019`. The standard formats for .NET [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: @BeckyPurland The format is not [in the list of CONVERT styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) either. The only thing you *can* do is find the values that fail: `select answer from BadTable where TRY_CONVERT(date,answer) is null`. Perhaps someone stored some weird string like `N/A` or `'NULL'` for missing values?

Comment: The convert part of the query works, as I stated in my question. The only part that fails in the where clause at the end. If I take out the where clause, the code runs perfectly, all dates come through ok and all Y and N's show correctly. What I do not understand is why it will not allow me to use the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and thank you to everyone who attempted to answer my query.

After many failed attempts and bringing in some SQL experts, we failed to find an answer.......Until today!

The issue lied in the data formatting. The answers had two possible formats, date and date/time, so this was causing the error to occur.

I fixed it by using substring to remove the time stamp from all dates, then converting them to dates. This seems to have worked fine and we now have a report that runs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `try_convert()` instead:

```
SELECT try_convert(date, A.answer) as CP,
       try_convert(date, B.answer) AS REF
```

You have invalid string values for the conversion.  However, SQL Server does not order the clauses in a query, so the filtering may not happen before the conversion.  `try_convert()` should fix the problem.

Comment: It does not work, I get this error 'String or binary data would be truncated.'

Comment: @BeckyPurland what string, what data? You haven't posted any information yet. Gordon's answer is the only way anyway. At best you can specify the conversion format - assuming all strings have the same format

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` isn't going to return the error `String or binary data would be truncated.`; meaning that something *else* is causing that. That sounds like you're trying to perform an `UPDATE` and provided a `varchar` that's too long for the column.

Answer (score 0):

See below query.Column names are not being recognized in case in you outer query.

You have to replace that with the actual converted date.Please see below.

```
    select
    CASE WHEN CP >= REF THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CPY
    from(
    SELECT
    convert(date,A.answer) as CP,
    convert(date,B.answer) AS REF
    from( table_a as A
    left join table_b as B on A.ID = B.ID)
    WHERE (CASE WHEN convert(date,A.answer) >= convert(date,B.answer)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END) = 0
```

Comment: That is how I have done it, I missed out a section of the code. I will amend the question.

Comment: The issue is with the datatype of column A.answer and B.answer.
Its type is Char and it cannot be converted in date.

Comment: @lts_ady I have managed to convert it and also create the case statement which works, so I don't believe that is the case. The only part that doesn't work is the where clause.

Comment: your current query (which you have posted in question ) seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query and let me know if still facing the `conversion error`.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CP >= REF
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS CPY
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(A.answer AS DATE) AS CP
        ,CAST(B.answer AS DATE) AS REF
    FROM table_a AS A
    LEFT JOIN table_b AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
    )
WHERE 0 = CASE 
        WHEN CP >= REF
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
```

Comment: CAST and CONVERT do the same job. If a row failed with one of them, it will fail with the other